# Mock and test MvvmCross NavigationService

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using the navigation service to perform the navigation between ViewModels and now I have to create some unit tests for my ViewModel. I am able to mock the ViewModel creating the injected objects with Moq but I am struggling to mock NavigationService and then create the assertion than it can navigate to the next ViewModel.

I have found some documentation from a couple of years ago so the navigation service did not exist and I cannot find anything about this matter at official MvvmCross documentation so right now I am in a dead end.

I am using MvvmCross 5.5.0.

```
[Test]
public void CheckStatus()
{
    Mock<IStatusService> _mockStatusService = new Mock<IStatusService>();
    _mockStatusService.Setup(x => x.Check(It.IsAny<StatusRequest>())).Returns(() => new StatusRequest { Ok = true });

    //Here I need to pass the NavigationService to the constructor
    var _viewModel = new StatusViewModel(_mockStatusService.Object, navigationService);
    _viewModel.Start();

    //Here I guess I should perform the navigation assertion.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to mock and test the NavigationService. I post here the solution because it would be useful for someone else.

```
[Test]
public void CheckStatus()
{
    IFixture _fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    Mock<IMvxNavigationService> _navigationService = _fixture.Freeze<Mock<IMvxNavigationService>>();

    var _viewModel = new StatusViewModel(navigationService);
    _viewModel.Start();

    _navigationService.Verify(x => x.Navigate<NextViewModel>(null), Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: You can use the ViewModelLoader to not manually call start or other methods.